# Transaction has been declined. Please try again later. - Error when invoicing

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, payment-gateway, braintree

We're using **Braintree** to process payments (**MCE 2.1.7**) and are running into issues where on the `braintree/paypal` side of things, everything gets processed and goes through fine, and we've been able to authorize, process and submit for settlement via the **Braintree** admin panel, however, when we attempt to create an invoice and capture the payment from the Magento admin, we keep receiving the following error:

> Transaction has been declined. Please try again later.

Has anybody experienced similar issues?

Comment: Did you have any solutions? I'm in the same issue as you do, but in mine issue, i tried to cancel the order and get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue when troubleshooting for a client earlier today. There is a bug with a work around, and a mismatch between accepted credit cards which can cause this.

Weltpixel (not affiliated) has a very nice write up on three possible solutions which helped me quickly resolve the issue.

https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007753688-How-we-solved-Braintree-Magento-2-checkout-issues-with-our-Magento-2-1-store

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, none of these scenarios are quite what we're encountering. The checkout process works fine, customers never see an error. The error occurs when we go into the order in the admin panel and try to capture funds/invoice the order.

Comment: Our payment method within Braintree's configuration is set to 'Authorize and Capture' so shouldn't the funds be captured when the order is processed? Is there any need for us to try capturing them via the magento admin panel? Maybe we're just seeing a delay in the funds posting to our account, as Braintree shows the transaction as settled?

Comment: If you are set to Auth & Capture, then at time of payment you have taken control of the funds. Really your only options at that point should be to deliver/ship the product or refund.

Comment: thanks for the info, that makes sense, and was how I figured it should work, so I'm thinking maybe we're just seeing a delay in it posting

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was user error. The error we were seeing within the Magento admin panel was being thrown because we were attempting to capture funds that had already been captured by Braintree, and we were just waiting to see the funds clear.